# Sleep duration manipulation in performing repitative bash command

Tags: bash

I have written the following simple code in bash to automate the Fortune program in Ubuntu. $1 takes the file name and another command line input takes the number of fortune to show consecutively with 10 sec sleep in between. I would like you to help me in modifying the code so that if i press ENTER key, the sleep time of 10 secs will reduce to zero that means it will show the next 'fortune'. Thanks

```
#function myfortunelearn
myfortunelearn(){
  cd $HOME/folder1/folder2
    numberofitems=$1
    shift
    echo -e "\n"
    for i in `seq $numberofitems`; do
       fortune $@
      sleep 10
      echo -e "\n"
    done
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to change:

```
sleep 10
```

To:

```
read -t 10
```

This will wait for input from the keyboard for 10 seconds, and return if it the timeout is exceeded without reading any input.